# Was Kerala part of Vijayanagara Empire under Deva Raya II

Tags: india, china

This question is in the context of my previous [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52193/was-kingdom-of-cochin-the-only-kingdom-in-south-asia-to-be-a-protectorate-of-an).

Wikipedia article on [Deva Raya 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_Raya_II) mentions that he defeated the ruler of Quilon, and also that Zamorin paid tribute to Deva Raya 2. But Kingdom of Cochin was under the protection of Ming Dynasty.  So, was Kingdom of Cochin under the suzerainty of Vijayanagara Empire, as the article says, or was it just alliance and co-belligerence?

Comment: It would certainly be possible for Cochin to become a protecorate of China about 1417 and later become a vassal or tributary of Vijayanagara Empire sometime in the reign of Deva Raya II (1425-1446).  The Bible may claim that no man can serve two masters at once, but history has many examples of persons and states doing that.  The last treasure voyage was from 1430-33 which gives time for Cochin and Ceylon to later pass under Vijayanagara overlordship.

Comment: @MAGolding Is there any indication (war, treaty, declaration, etc) that the relationship was that of suzerainty and not alliance and friendship?